# Iterate MySql query result inside another loop in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there any solution to iterate one `MySql query` result inside another loop using ruby.

Using Ruby `mysql` Gem

In my code `fetch_row` will not accept any parameters. so my code will return error.

```
connection = Mysql.new(@db_host, @db_user, @db_pass, @db_name)
total_make = connection.query("Select make COUNT(cartype) AS cnt FROM vehicles group by car order by car;")
result = connection.query("Select make, cartype, COUNT(cartype) AS cnt FROM vehicles where cartype='suv' group by car order by car;")
suv = 0
data = ""
i = 0
result.each do |row|
    suv += row[1].to_i
    total_make.fetch_row(i)
    data +=  row[0] + "\n"
    data += "Total Cars: " + total_make[1] + "\n"
    data += "Total SUV : " + suv.to_s + "\n"
    data += "-----------------------\n"
    data = ""
    i+=1
end

puts data
```

**MySql Query:**

```
Select make, cartype, COUNT(cartype) AS cnt FROM vehicles where cartype='suv' group by car order by car;

+-----------+-----------+-----+
|    make   |  cartype  | cnt |
+-----------+-----------+-----+
|    Ford   |    suv    |   2 |
|   Toyota  |    suv    |   3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----+

Select make COUNT(cartype) AS cnt FROM vehicles group by car order by car;

+-----------+-----+
|    make   | cnt |
+-----------+-----+
|    Ford   |   4 |
|   Toyota  |   5 |
+-----------+-----+
```

**Expected result:**

Trying to group cars by make and list total cars, total suv.

```
Totota
Total Cars: 5
Total SUV : 3
-----------------------
Ford
Total Cars: 4
Total SUV : 2
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what it is you're asking for exactly, or how to use the `mysql` gem to its fullest advantage, but this is how I would produce your expected result the Rails way.

```
#in the controller
@cars = Cars.all


#in the view
<% @cars.group_by{|a| a[:make]}.each do |key, group| %>
  <%= key %><br>
  Total Cars: <%= group.size %><br>
  Total SUV: <%= group.where(:cartype => "suv").size %><br>
  ------------------
<% end %>
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is `Iterate MySql query result inside another loop in pure ruby way` you can check the do loop section in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. I have not tested it though.

```
i=0
result.each do |row|

total_make.first(i).each do |make|
make_count_value = make['cnt'] 
end 

data += "Total Cars: " + row['cnt'] "\n"
data += "Total SUV : " + make_count_value "\n"
data += "-----------------------\n"
data = ""

i=i+1
end
```

Comment: For total cars i have another mysql query `total_make`. `row['cnt']` wil give the working result.

Comment: `fetch_row` will not accept any parameters. is there any other way to iterate.

Comment: if you are using rails, why are you coding in pure ruby?? Is there any reason? I am curious? Because doing the rails way makes it lot more simpler.

Comment: you are mistaken, i am not using Rails. I tagged my question in rails, so that some rails developers can also help me.

Comment: I know using ruby will solve my problem. I'ts only a small script, thats why not using `RoR Framework`.

Comment: you can loop the 2 queries in 2 separate 'each loop' also. And append the result.